# How to exclude bundle.css from index.html generated by html-webpack-plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I want to use html-webpack-plugin **only** for my js chunks.
Bundle.css is generated by extract-text-plugin:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'bundle.css, allChunks: true})
```

HtmlWebpackPlugin options:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'template/tpl.html', inject: true})
```

My tpl.html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Cash Management</title>
    <link href="getResource?resource=build/bundle.css&mediaType=text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id='root' />
</body>

</html>
```

I want to see something like this in my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Cash Management</title>
    <link href="getResource?moduleName=cm-ui&resource=build/bundle.css&mediaType=text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id='root' />
</body>
  <script href="getResource?moduleName=cm-ui&resource=build/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script href="getResource?moduleName=cm-ui&resource=build/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: By a quick look i saw a typo in your key `allCunks : true`. => `allChunks: true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [html-webpack-exclude-assets-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-exclude-assets-plugin)

With it you can exclude assets which prevent them from being pasted automatically.
Also you still can insert path to your template with lodash syntax.

```
<link href="getResource?resource=<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[0] %>&mediaType=text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```